# Eventlet timeout not exiting

Tags: python, eventlet

Why does eventlet allow it to finish the 6 seconds, when it should exit the indentation after 5 seconds?

```
>>> with eventlet.Timeout(5):
        time.sleep(6)
        x = 1
>>> x
1
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're supposed to use `eventlet.sleep` if you want an eventlet greenthread to sleep.

Comment: @user2357112 is this something particular to sleep or if i use other calls, it also won't exit them halfway through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventlet provides cooperative multithreading. Which means you need to yield control to give hub or coroutines (in this case, hub implements timeouts) chance to run. To yield control:

- either use green versions of IO and sleep
- or execute `eventlet.monkey_patch()`, now you can use regular `time`, `socket`, etc modules, replaced by "green" versions, cooperating with Eventlet.

Any CPU tight code without green calls, for example `[_ for _ in xrange(1000000000)]` is impossible to interrupt at all. If you find yourself in similar situation, place `eventlet.sleep(0)` somewhere in loop, that would enter Eventlet hub and allow timeouts to work.