# How can I raise Exception using eventlet in Python?

Tags: python, eventlet

I have a simply code:

import eventlet

```
def execute():
    print("Start")
    timeout = Timeout(3)
    try:
        print("First")
        sleep(4)
        print("Second")
    except:
        raise TimeoutException("Error")
    finally:
        timeout.cancel()
    print("Third")
```

This code should throw TimeoutException, because code in 'try' block executing more than 3 seconds.
But this exception shallows in the loop. I can't see it in the output

This is output:

```
Start
First

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How can I raise this exception to the output?

Answer (score 4):

Change sleep(4) to

```
eventlet.sleep(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will not output `Start...` because nobody calls `execute()`, also `sleep` is not defined. Show real code, I will edit answer.

For now, several speculations:

- maybe you have `from time import sleep`, then it's a duplicate of [Eventlet timeout not exiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795353/eventlet-timeout-not-exiting) and the problem is that you don't give Eventlet a chance to run and realize there was a timeout, solutions: `eventlet.sleep()` everywhere or `eventlet.monkey_patch()` once.
- maybe you don't import sleep at all, then it's a `NameError: sleep` and all exceptions from `execute` are hidden by caller.
- maybe you run this code with `stderr` redirected to file or `/dev/null`.

Let's also fix other issues.

```
try:
  # ...
  sleeep()  # with 3 'e', invalid name
  open('file', 'rb')
  raise Http404
except:
  # here you catch *all* exceptions
  # in Python 2.x even SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt, GeneratorExit
  #  - things you normally don't want to catch
  # but in any Python version, also NameError, IOError, OSError,
  # your application errors, etc, all irrelevant to timeout
  raise TimeoutException("Error")
```

In Python 2.x you **never** write `except:` only `except Exception:`.

So let's catch only proper exceptions.

```
try:
  # ...
  execute_other() # also has Timeout, but shorter, it will fire first
except eventlet.Timeout:
  # Now there may be other timeout inside `try` block and
  # you will accidentally handle someone else's timeout.
  raise TimeoutException("Error")
```

So let's verify that it was yours.

```
timeout = eventlet.Timeout(3)
try:
  # ...
except eventlet.Timeout as t:
  if t is timeout:
    raise TimeoutException("Error")
  # else, reraise and give owner of another timeout a chance to handle it
  raise
```

Here's same code with shorter syntax:

```
with eventlet.Timeout(3, TimeoutException("Error")):
  print("First")
  eventlet.sleep(4)
  print("Second")
print("Third")
```

I hope you really need to substitute one timeout exception for another.